# Type mismatch Excel VBA – If to continue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a quick script to select and duplicate specific rows, but running into an issue. I keep receiving the error "Type Mismatch" in reference to the line :

```
If rng = "" Then
```

I'm new to this and I'm thinking I'm grabbing an object and this is looking for  string, but my fall back is PHP. I couldn't find a way to var_dump to grab the value to double check that. I'm not sure if it's valid to convert to a string which I tried, but couldn't seem to get that to apply correctly. Any ideas what could be happening here?

```
    Sub duplicateRows()
'
' duplicateRows Macro
'
Dim lastCellOnRow As String
Dim lastCellOnRow2 As String
'Dim rng As String
Dim rangeHere As String
Dim lColDuplicate As Long
Dim lRowDuplicate As Long
Dim theActiveCell As String
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
' Build the variables for selection
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRowDuplicate = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lColDuplicate = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    theActiveCell = "B3:" & Col_Letter(lColDuplicate) & "3"
    theActiveCell = theActiveCell

'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'Make selection and create variable for how many are selected
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    'ActiveSheet.Range(theActiveCell).Select

    'selectionCount = Selection.Cells.Count
    'MsgBox selectionCount

Dim n As Integer, rng As Range
'n = InputBox("type the value of n")
Set rng = Range(theActiveCell)
rng.Select
line2:
'n = InputBox("type no. of times you want to be repeated minus 1 for e.g if you wnat to be repeated 3 times type 2")
Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(2, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range(rng, rng.Offset(2, 0)).PasteSpecial
Set rng = rng.Offset(2 + 1, 0)
'CStr(rng)
'RangeToString (rng)
'MsgBox rng
If rng = "" Then
GoTo line1
Else
GoTo line2
End If
line1:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("a1").Select
MsgBox "macro over"


End Sub
```

Edit: I just thought about something regarding the if. I wonder if it would make more sense to if out the range rather than a string (""). That may be the wrong way to think about VBA. Again I'm working through this with a preference for PHP.

Comment: `rng` is a multi-cell range - you can't compare it to a scalar `""`.  (VBA doesn't cater for array operations such as that.)

Comment: What is your `If rng = "" Then` meant to be testing for?  Are you trying to see if **all** the cells in the range are blank?  Or are you trying to test if **any** of the cells in the range is blank?  Or something else?

Comment: @YowE3K . I appreciate that clarification. From my quick research scalar variables  are those that aren't arrays. If it's not an array wouldn't it be classified as a variable with a value?

Comment: If any of the cells in the row are empty, that would disqualify it.

Comment: Providing you don't have any cells containing actual blanks (e.g. a formula that returns `""`) then I think you can use something like `If rng.Columns.Count <> Application.CountA(rng) Then`

Comment: That most definitely resolves the error. A quick question for you regarding the difference between what I was trying to do and what you did there. If it's scalar, what exactly are we counting? The object itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162236/discussion-between-user3135730-and-yowe3k).

Comment: `rng` is a vector, perhaps referring to the cells in B6:K6.  Actually, it is more appropriate to say it is an array, because Excel treats it as two-dimensional, but the first dimension in this case is a single row.  So it is a 1 x 10 array.  Meanwhile `""` is a scalar.  VBA doesn't allow comparisons of arrays to scalars.  (It doesn't allow comparisons of arrays to arrays either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to determine whether **any** cell in your `rng` object is blank, you can replace

```
If rng = "" Then
```

with

```
If rng.Columns.Count <> Application.CountA(rng) Then
```

---

FWIW, refactored code incorporating other modifications we mentioned in chat could be:

```
Sub duplicateRows()
    Dim lColDuplicate As Long
    Dim lRowDuplicate As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column C
    lRowDuplicate = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 3
    lColDuplicate = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For r = lRowDuplicate To 3 Step -1
        Rows((r + 1) & ":" & (r + 2)).Insert
        For c = 2 To lColDuplicate
            'duplicate data as [xyz]
            Cells(r + 1, c).Value = "[" & Cells(r, c).Value & "]"
            'duplicate data as "xyz"
            Cells(r + 2, c).Value = """" & Cells(r, c).Value & """"
        Next
    Next
    MsgBox "macro over"
End Sub
```